# Pipe md5sum output to a specific file line

Tags: sed, io-redirection

I have found some "almost good" examples, but none of them worked as it should.

I have a file **a.txt** and a file **checkme.txt**.
I want to execute the md5sum checkme.txt command and write it as a **10th line** of the **a.txt** file.

I tried to use the *sed* command, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What if `a.txt` has less than ten lines?

Comment: sorry, didn't mention. `a.txt` has more than 10 lines. I want to **replace** 10th line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed '10 s/.*/'"$(md5sum checkme.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)"'/' a.txt
```

- `10 s/.*/<md5sum result>/` - substitute content of the 10th line

Comment: this one works almost great. I forgot to specify, that I want to **replace** 10th line, not "put the line between". Is it possible?

Comment: @EmilBeza, see my update

Answer (score 0):

An `ed` solution:

```
printf '10d\n-1r !md5sum checkme.txt\n' | ed -s a.txt
```

The `ed` script:

```
10d
-1r !md5sum checkme.txt
```

This deletes the 10th line of `a.txt` and then inserts the output of `md5sum checkme.txt` in its place.  This won't actually do much as the result is not displayed nor saved.

To write the result to the terminal:

```
printf '10d\n-1r !md5sum checkme.txt\n,p\n' | ed -s a.txt
```

To write the result back to `a.txt`:

```
printf '10d\n-1r !md5sum checkme.txt\nw\n' | ed -s a.txt
```

If `a.txt` has less than 10 lines, no modification to the file will be made.

Comment: this one looks very wise, but I am not able to use the ed. Is it possible to do this with **sed** ?

Comment: @EmilBeza I believe that Roman's answer could easily be modified to do what you need with `sed`.